# AAC HE-AACv2 file replay on smartphone Cubot R15 Pro with Android 9.0 fails

Tags: audio

**AAC replay on smartphone Cubot R15 Pro with Android 9.0 fails**

When I tried to replay recorded music from [www.afc.fm](http://www.afc.fm), my smartphone fails to replay it.

MediaInfo reports the following info about the audio file in question (not uploaded, would be probably illegal):

```
Audio
Format                                   : AAC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec
Format-Version                           : Version 2
Format-Profil                            : HE-AACv2 / HE-AAC / LC
Bitraten-Modus                           : variabel
Kanäle                                   : 2 Kanäle / 1 Kanal / 1 Kanal
Kanal-Positionen                         : Front: L R / Front: C / Front: C
Samplingrate                             : 44,1 KHz / 44,1 KHz / 22,05 KHz
Stream-Größe                             : 1,52 MiB (100%)
```

The phone is a Cubot R15 Pro with Android 9.0.
According to
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats
Android should play HE-AACv2 starting with version 3.0 already.

What did I do wrong or what is necessary to make the smartphone play those recordings?

Coudl somebody with sufficient reputation tag this question with "aac" and "he-aac v2"?

Comment: Have you read the sentence `Codecs that are not guaranteed to be available on all Android platform versions are noted in parentheses`? for HE-AACv2 all entries are shown in parentheses hence they are optional if I interpret the codec list correctly. More relevant may be the list of encodings that have to be supported: https://source.android.com/compatibility/android-cdd#5_multimedia_compatibility Also make sure you are using the correct container format that is marked as supported.

Comment: Robert, thank you. This is a very interesting source I was not aware of. If I understand it correctly then HE AACv2 is only supported in a MP4-Container. My files ends with ".aac" though.

Comment: did you try with some app, for example MX Player or VLC

Comment: After learning now that some apps do not rely on operating system support and use their own code or third party libraries I found some apps.